# Codeigniter Remove "Reply To:"

Tags: php

When i open my email program it will show.

```
From: no-reply@domain.com 
To: myaccount@domain2.com 
Reply To: no-reply@domain.com
```

The question is to remove

```
Reply To: no-reply@domain.com
```

from the email?
I know it is possible, because i use IPB and there it does not show.

Comment: You want to remove the header or change it to something else?

Comment: Found it,

    system\libraries\Email.php Line: 1362

Comment the folling line

    $this->reply_to($this->_headers['From']);

Comment: @Ramesh ye i think its in the header, but this seems to work, i have no idea if this is the proper way to do it, but it seems to work

Comment: Not good to change the System Library files

Comment: @Ramesh, ye, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

Found it,

```
system\libraries\Email.php 
Line: 1362
```

Comment the follwing line

```
$this->reply_to($this->_headers['From']);
```